# How do you save time from a timer in php and javascript project before a post?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to php and whilst creating a project of mine , I created a timer counting up for my quiz , when i try to save the time(submit my quiz answers) to a local file lets say 10 seconds into the quiz when it saves it gives a remotely different time such as 22:25 even if the timer counts up perfectly. If you can suggest a solution or show where I went wrong please tell me .

extra info:
I made two pages for the quiz and on the first page I made it so it simply found the time the user takes and their selection of options , so I can later calculate best time if there is a new one and their score all info would be sent to local docs.

When I submit the answers to my quiz I expect it to save the time taken for the user, from the loading of the page till their submission of options. however it has always sent different remotely different times , I've tried using JavaScript and a few different versions slightly different to no avail, along with a few similar posts here but I still have no idea where the issue lies. If it is a repeated question im oblivious of, please tell me id rather no waste others time.

code to my php page:( I bolded the areas I think might be the issue or related to it, mostly at the bottom)

```
\<?php
// Start a new or resume the existing PHP session
session_start();

// Initialize the user's score if it doesn't exist in the session
if (!isset($\_SESSION\["score"\])) {
$\_SESSION\["score"\] = 0;
}

// Initialize an array to store the user's answers if it doesn't exist in the session
if (!isset($\_SESSION\["answers"\])) {
$\_SESSION\["answers"\] = array();
}

// Initialize a variable to store the user's answers as 'a b c d'
$user_answers = '';

// Define the file names for the questions and answers
$questions_file = 'Questions.txt';
$answers_file = 'Answers.txt';

// Read the content of the questions file into a variable
$file_content = file_get_contents($questions_file);

// Split the questions into an array using double line breaks as separators
$questions = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $file_content);

// Read the correct answers from the answers file and store them in an array
$correct_answers = file($answers_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// Initialize a variable to count unanswered questions
$unanswered = 0;

// Check if the form has been submitted using the HTTP POST method
if ($\_SERVER\["REQUEST_METHOD"\] === "POST") {
// Loop through the questions and process the answers
foreach ($questions as $index =\> $question_data) {
// Limit the number of processed questions to 9
if ($index \>= 9) {
break; // Stop processing questions after the first 9
}

        // Generate the name of the radio button option based on the question index
        $option_name = 'q' . ($index + 1);
    
        // Check if the option has been selected by the user
        if (isset($_POST[$option_name])) {
            $selected_option = $_POST[$option_name];
    
            // Check if the selected option is correct
            if ($selected_option == $correct_answers[$index]) {
                $_SESSION["answers"][$index] = true; // Store that the question was answered correctly
                $_SESSION["score"]++; // Increment the user's score
    
                // Save the user's score to 'sascore.txt'
                file_put_contents('sascore.txt', $_SESSION["score"]);
            } else {
                $_SESSION["answers"][$index] = false; // Store that the question was answered incorrectly
            }
    
            // Collect the selected options and format them as 'a b c d'
            $user_answers .= $selected_option . PHP_EOL; // Use PHP_EOL to separate answers by lines
        } else {
            // Count unanswered questions
            $unanswered++;
            $_SESSION["answers"][$index] = false; // Store that the question was unanswered
        }
    }
    
    // Save the user's answers to 'useranswer.txt'
    file_put_contents('Useranswer.txt', $user_answers);
  //////////////////// some timer related code   
    **// Save the current time to 'currenttime.txt'
    $current_time = date('i:s');
    file_put_contents('currenttime.txt', $current_time);
    **
    // Redirect to 'xxxxxxxx' after submitting the form
    header("Location: xxxxxxxxx");
    exit(); // Ensure that no further code is executed after the redirection
//////////////
}

// Read the best time from the savedtime.txt file
$best_time = file_get_contents('savedtime.txt');
?\>

<!DOCTYPE html>



  ///// a bunch of css

    <div class="score-container">
        Score: <?php echo $_SESSION["score"]; ?> / 9 <!-- Update this line for 9 questions -->
        <?php
        // Display the number of unanswered questions if any
        if ($unanswered > 0) {
            echo ' (' . $unanswered . ' unanswered)';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Display the best time achieved by the user -->
    <div class="best-time-container">
        Best Time: <?php echo $best_time; ?>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Create a container for the quiz questions and form -->
    <div class="quiz-container">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <?php
            // Loop through the questions and display them
            foreach ($questions as $index => $question_data) {
                // Limit the number of displayed questions to 9
                if ($index >= 9) {
                    break; // Stop displaying questions after the first 9
                }
                // Split the question data into lines
                $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $question_data);
                // Extract the question text
                $question = $lines[0];
                // Extract the answer options
                $options = array_slice($lines, 1, 4);
    
                // Display the question
                echo '<div class="question">';
                echo '<p>' . $question . '</p>';
                // Display the answer options as radio buttons
                foreach ($options as $optionIndex => $option) {
                    echo '<div class="option">';
                    $optionValue = substr($option, 3, 1);
                    $optionId = 'q' . ($index + 1) . chr(97 + $optionIndex); // Generate option ID using letters (a, b, c, d)
                    $optionName = 'q' . ($index + 1);
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $optionName . '" value="' . $optionValue . '" id="' . $optionId . '"';
    
                    // Check if this option was selected previously
                    if (isset($_POST[$optionName]) && $_POST[$optionName] == $optionValue) {
                        echo ' checked';
                    }
    
                    echo '>';
                    echo '<label for="' . $optionId . '">' . $option . '</label>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
    
                // Display user's answers and correct answers after submission
                if (isset($_POST['q' . ($index + 1)])) {
                    echo '<div class="option">';
                    if ($_SESSION["answers"][$index] === true) {
                        echo '<span class="correct">Your answer: ' . $_POST['q' . ($index + 1)] . '</span>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<span class="incorrect">Your answer: ' . $_POST['q' . ($index + 1)] . '</span>';
                        echo '<span class="correct">Correct answer: ' . $correct_answers[$index] . '</span>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
    
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
            <!-- Create buttons for submitting answers and resetting the quiz -->
            <div class="submit-button">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers">
            </div>
            <div class="reset-button">
                <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Quiz">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    ///////////////////// timer related code
  **  <!-- Display a timer that tracks the time spent on the quiz -->
    <div class="timer-container" id="timer">Time: 00:00</div>
    <script>
        // JavaScript code to update and display the timer
        let startTime = Date.now();
        let timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
    
        function updateTimer() {
            let currentTime = Date.now();
            let elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
            let seconds = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000);
            let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds %= 60;
    
            // Format the time as HH:MM:SS
            let formattedTime = (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
            timerElement.innerText = 'Time: ' + formattedTime;
        }
    
        window.onload = function () {
            // Update the timer every second
            setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
        };
    </script>
//////////////////
**
```

Comment: You are saving the current minute and second from the servers real time clock to "currenttime.txt", where do you try to figure out how look the user took to complete the quiz?